# How can I convert a string to char[] without copying the object?

Tags: java, string, char, java-8

I have a string and I need to traverse it as a char array.
Of course the normal method is to use `toCharArray()`

```
String str = "Hello";
char[] charArr = str.toCharArray();
```

Now, the source code for toCharArray() is as follows.

```
public char[] toCharArray() {
    // Cannot use Arrays.copyOf because of class initialization order issues
    char result[] = new char[value.length];
    System.arraycopy(value, 0, result, 0, value.length);
    return result;
}
```

So Java is creating a new object in memory of type char[] and copying the string object to the new object.

My question is whether or not it is possible to use a string as a char[] without copying the array. My intention is to save on memory space. If this is not possible, is there a reason so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Handing off a direct reference to a mutable `char[]` array of an object that is supposed to be immutable, would be a very bad idea, especially if the immutable object in question if of type `String`, which has to fulfill security relevant roles.

Comment: If you want to save memory space, don’t ask for the `char[]` array. You didn’t explain, why you think you need it.

Comment: I need an array so that I can iterate through it by index. However, what I didn't realize and what Nicolas Filotto pointed out is that Strings are simply a class that stores the string in a `char[]` array. Doy! Beginners mistake :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

No, it isn't. Not without reflection, which you should avoid. Messing with the underlying `char[]` in a string via reflection is a recipe for subtle bugs. You can access individual characters in a string using `charAt`, but if you really need a `char[]` you should just call `toCharArray`.

> If this is not possible, is there a reason so?

First reason: encapsulation. The array is a private implementation detail.

Second reason: immutability. Strings are immutable, but arrays *never* are. So you could modify the underlying char array, and the string would be mutated, much to the surprise of any developer relying on the normal immutability.

Comment: And additionally, other references to the same string in the string pool would also have the same mutated string, leading to greater confusion.

Comment: @Pokechu22: even worse, security policies (permissions, code sources, user names) are stored as strings, so allowing to change them would undermine the entire security model.

Answer (score 4):

Here is how you can traverse a `String` somehow as a `char` array without using `toCharArray()` :

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
}
```

Comment: Well not the "it" that the OP was asking about... if the OP only has a method accepting a `char[]` that they can't modify, for example, this isn't going to help at all.

Comment: And where you store these generated char's ?

Comment: "I have a string and I need to traverse it as a char array" this is the main request of the OP, what I propose help in traversing the String, if it is not what the OP expects he needs to modify the question

Comment: This is actually exactly what I wanted! This points out something that I did not realize which is that the class String simply stores its contents in a char array called value[].

Using str.charAt(int index) simply returns value[index]

Answer (score 3):

Since you are expecting the array back, there is no way to get an array without creating a new array.

This is the cleanest way. Even though you create your own function and do some trick, you'll end up in creating new array.

Go  with your current codes.